# Android app showing ellipses as &hellip;

Tags: bug, android-app, html-entities, mobile-app

The Android app, when showing replies, for the ellipses, it shows `&hellip;` instead. I presume this would be the same for other 'special' characters, I see that there is already a bug report for the main site notifications, but I thought it's different for the app.

[image]

Note: this only happens on the 'feed', it is displayed correctly in the notification list on the app and website

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4, app version 1.0.51. Take note that only the entity on the "Feed" is problematic. The same notification inside the notification drawer is displayed properly.

Comment: True. Quick question -  did you just post that testing comment?

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to test the issue on my device, but I did it wrong. So I deleted it. Nice finding btw :)

Comment: Yeah I just posted a question about getting notifications for deleted comments so I wanted to ask you whether it was correct. I also see the *original* comment - you must have said 'unicode' and then edited it to 'entity', am I right?

Comment: Yep, you're correct.